# postCss + webpack + scss настройка

Tags: webpack, scss, postcss

В своих проектах я использую `scss`, а в качестве сборщика `gulp` и мне этого честно сказать хватает. Но вот дернула меня  нечистая поковырять webpack, хороший инструмент к слову, думаю разобраться с ним полностью.
И вот пришла очередь настраивать сборку стилей в нем, сделав все как описано в документации, установив все нужные загрузчики, мои стили на scss прекрасно компилировались в `css`.
Но вот при подключении таких плюшек как автопрефиксер, объединение медиазапросов в документации написано, что предпочтительней не использовать `autoprefixer-loader` отдельно, а в качестве плагина к `postcss-loder`.
Ну хорошо подумал я и пошел читать про этот самый `postcss`, мне понравилась его идея и решил использовать его для стилей, но вот не задача, я привык к синтаксису `scss` и хотелось бы продолжать писать стили в том же духе... И вот здесь возникают проблемы в понимании документации:
цитата из доки к postcss

> Опции
>
> Большинство сред, запускающих плагины PostCSS принимают два параметра:
>
> ```
> массив плагинов
> объект с опциями
> ```
>
> Общие параметры:
>
> ```
> syntax: объект, предоставляющий синтаксический анализатор.
> parser: специальный пасрер синтаксиса (например, SCSS).
> ```

Я так понимаю мне нужно в поле `syntax` указать что - то вроде `require('postcss-scss')`, а в настройках `webpack` поменять местами `'sass-loader'` и `'postcss-loader'`, т.е. сначала запускаться должен postcss, он добавит всё необходимое в код, а затем уже `libsass` закомпилит все в `css`?
Или же вообще отказаться от файлов `.scss` использовать только `postcss`, установив `precss` для поддержки `scss` систаксиса, как написано в [статье](https://oriolo.ru/perehod-s-scss-na-postcss-moj-opyt/)
Совсем запутался, может кто внятно мне объяснить что, куда и зачем?